# Delta Lake - "mergeSchema" vs "autoMerge"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am currently reading on Delta Lake schema evolution and I'm having trouble understanding what's the difference between the "mergeSchema" `DataFrameWriter` option and the "autoMerge" `SparkSession` configuration. I get that the former is just an option used during a specific write to a Delta table, while the latter is a more general configuration that applies to the whole Spark session, but other than that, is there any difference in relation to what they actually achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option (`mergeSchema`) is for normal writes, when you do `df.write.format("delta")....`.  The second one (`spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled`, [doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#automatic-schema-evolution)) is for schema evolution when you perform MERGE operation that is a separate operation, not a "normal write".

Comment: Oh I see. So I'm guessing that even if I enable "autoMerge" for the SparkSession, a normal write to the table will fail, if I'm writing data with a different (though of incremental type) schema without enabling "mergeSchema".

Comment: Yes. That’s correct

Comment: And a follow-up question if you may: Does "autoMerge" support the exact same type of evolution schema as "mergeSchema", or are there any differences between the two?

Comment: It may depend on the Delta version, in versions 0.6-0.8, there were some differences. If I remember correctly, now they should be the same, but this need confirmation - I think documentation contains a full list of supported options for both of them

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to answer!